# SharePoint 2013 - Related List Web Parts

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, lookup-column

I have two related lists (parent-child relationship) in my SharePoint 2013 site.

The child list contains a lookup column containing the unique titles that exist in the parent list. I have added the related child list as a web part to the parent list's default display form. When a parent item is opened, the child items are filtered accordingly.

My question:

Is there a way that I can allow the summary toolbar on the child web part so when a user clicks on the "add new item" link, the parent title is passed to the child's New Item form so I can automatically set the lookup drop down box to the proper selection?

Thanks,
BL

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge, that will be hard to accomplish your goal. We cannot directly get the parent list value and send to the new item form window.

Answer (score 0):

Update:  I was able to accomplish the task mentioned above by adding some jQuery to the parent page that basically read the parentID querystring value and passed it along to the child newForm page.  Inside the newForm page of the child, I look for the querystring value containing the parentID.  If it exists, I am setting the value and disabling the drop down box.  In the case where one might access the child form directly to add a new item, there will be no parentID value available so the user must select the Parent ID.